# How to get a table automatically updated when another table is updated Using C#

Tags: c#, mysql, database, auto-update

How to get a table automatically updated when another table is updated Using C#

Hi all, I have 4 (four) tables using MySql database, ie:

```
tb_item (
id_item, (varchar) --> PK
item_name, (varchar)
price, (double)
)

tb_order (
id_order, (varchar) --> PK
id_item, (varchar) -->FK
date_order, (date)
lead_time, (float)
order_quantity, (double)
)

tb_use (
id_use, (varchar) --> PK
id_item, (varchar) -->FK
date_use, (date)
use_quantity, (double)
)

tb_inventory (
id_inventory, (varchar) --> PK
id_item, (varchar) --> FK
id_order, (varchar) --> FK
id_use, (varchar) --> FK
item_stock, (double)
)
```

My problem is I want to **item_stock** in **tb_inventory** automatically updated: when **tb_order.order_quantity** or **tb_use.use_quantity** are updated, then **tb_inventory.item_stock** will updated automatically by using a calculation “**tb_order.order_quantity – tb_use.use_quantity = tb_inventory.item_stock**” (Example: 10 - 7 = 3). and vice versa.
How to create code for the problem in C#.

Please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html), but it would be better to normalize your database so that this information is stored only in one place. If you use triggers and somewhow the database is incorrectly updated, that error can persist for a long time unnoticed.

An alternative is to create a view which calculates the amount of stock by querying the other tables. This will give a slight performance hit because the value will have to be recalculated every time it is requested. This performance hit can be partially solved by adding indexes to make the recalculation very fast. In the end it depends on whether you are more interested in raw speed, or consistency and correctness of the result.

Comment: Hi Mark... Thank you for your response..

Can you teach me how to create a view to update the table? I do not know about view. I am using MySql database. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You don't create a view to update a table, you query the view instead of the table.